# How can I prevent the creation of subfolders on S3 with KnpGaufretteBundle

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3, symfony-2.4, gaufrette

I have configured [KnpGaufretteBundle](http://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle) to write file uploads to Amazon S3. Files are uploaded but additional subfolders named based on the current date are added. Howe can I prevent this?

```
knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
        image_storage:
            amazon_s3:
                amazon_s3_id: mynamespace_admin.amazon_s3
                bucket_name:  %amazon_s3_bucket_name%
                create:       false
                options:
                    create:     true
                    directory: 'mydirectory'
                    region:     %amazon_s3_region%


    filesystems:
        image_storage:
            adapter:    image_storage
            alias:      image_storage_filesystem
```

Answer (score 1):

This was not caused by KnpGaufretteBundle, there was a sprintf() call on the uploaded filename adding the path which was causing the folders to be created